# An eigen-decomposition problem with Kronecker product

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, kronecker-product, matrix-analysis

First define a function $P$ mapping matrix into matrix of dimension $m$ by $m$, given $V$ and $L$
$$P(A)=V^T(L\otimes A)(L\otimes A)^TV$$
where $L$ is $N$ by $N$ and $V = [v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_m]$, {$v_i$} is orthonormal in $\mathbf{R}^{Nn}$ and $A$ is a $n$ by $d$ matrix with constraints $d<n$ and full column rank, is there any way to find eigenvector of $P$ (in terms of something related to $A$) ?

My thought is to use SVD of $L$ and $A$ $$P(A)=V^T(U_L\otimes U_A)(\Sigma_L\otimes \Sigma_A)(\Sigma_L\otimes \Sigma_A)^T(U_L\otimes U_A)V = V^TU_{LA}D_{LA}U_{LA}^TV =SD_{LA}S^T$$
where I denote $(U_L\otimes U_A)$ by $U_{LA}$ and $D_L \otimes D_A$ by $D_{LA}$ ($D_L = \Sigma_L\Sigma_L^T$, $D_A = \Sigma_A\Sigma_A^T$ ) and $S = V^TU_{LA}$
Then we have a form look like eigen-decomposition ($SS^T = I_m$) but the dimension of $S$ is $m$ by $Nd$ (if we apply thin or economy SVD) not $m$ by $m$, I have no idea about future steps. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that we can rewrite your expression as 
$$
P(A) = V^T[(LL^T) \otimes (AA^T)]V.
$$
It is easy to characterize the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the "inner matrix" $(LL^T) \otimes (AA^T)$ in terms of the SVDs of $A$ and $L$. However, the matrix $P(A)$ is ultimately a [compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compression_(functional_analysis)) of this matrix, and it is not easy to obtain the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of a submatrix (or more general compression) using the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of the original matrix.

Comment: That said, there are formulas you can use to obtain the eigenvectors of the "compressed" matrix if you know the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the original matrix; see [this recent paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.03795) for more details.

Comment: In my case I assume eigen decomposition of $A$ is known once we have an input $A$. But your paper deal with 'minor'. How to apply to the compression of this case?  Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Extend the columns of $V$ to form an orthogonal matrix $W = [V \ \ V_2]$. It is easy to get the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of the matrix $W^TMW$ from the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of $M = (LL^) \otimes (AA^T)$. The matrix $P(A)$ is the upper-left $m \times m$ minor of $W^TMW$.

Comment: Also I wonder am I on the right way to this problem (simplify it into $SDS^T$) ? Or it is to complicated to proceed ?

Comment: Your method is in essence the same as what I suggest. Instead of getting $P(A)$ as a compression of $(LL^T) \otimes (AA^T)$, you get $P(A)$ as a compression of the diagonal matrix $D_{LA}$.

Comment: Oh I don‘t realize that, thank you for your solution!

Comment: Is there a closed form solution for eigenvectors?  I have trouble finding them by the method mentioned above.

Comment: Not really. At best, you could use the paper I linked to get a closed form for the eigenvectors of $P(A)$ in terms of the eigenvalues of $P(A)$.

Comment: The paper only talk about relationship between the eigenvalues of minors and eigen decomposition of $A$, not eigenvectors of minors, isn't it? Or I misunderstood that?